# Javascript (Typescript) nested for-loop updating all elements, not just the inner loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, typescript

When using for-loop in Typescript, for some reason the for loop updates the whole array. Here is the code:

```
UpdatesToAllSelectedTabs() {

    if (this.selectedOuterTabs[1]) {
        this.outerTabs[1].InnerTabs = this.outerTabs[this.referencedOuterTab].InnerTabs;
        for (let j = 0; j < this.outerTabs[1].InnerTabs.length; j++) {
            this.outerTabs[1].InnerTabs[j].OuterTabId = this.outerTabs[1].Id;
        }
    }
}
```

The first version of the code had also the outer loop, but it also doesn't work proper with the fixed outer index ( in example above = 1).
What this piece of code does, is the following:

If selected,
copies the innerTabs from the referenced outerTab[0] to outerTab[1]. Which is ok.
Then,
it sets the ...innerTabs[j].OuterTabId from both outerTabs[1] and outerTabs[0] to the this.outerTabs[1].Id.

Can someone please explain what is happening here? Why are the outerTab[0] also updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this line:

```
this.outerTabs[1].InnerTabs = this.outerTabs[this.referencedOuterTab].InnerTabs;
```

It seems that `this.outerTabs[1]` is referencing the same object as `this.outerTabs[this.referencedOuterTab]`, so if you change one you change the other one as well.

A simpler example of the problem:

```
let arr1 = [{ key: "value1" }, { key: "value2" }, { key: "value3" }];
let arr2 = new Array(...arr1);

console.log(arr1[1]); // {key: "value2"}
console.log(arr2[1]); // {key: "value2"}

arr2[1].key = "value2.2"

console.log(arr1[1]); // {key: "value2.2"}
console.log(arr2[1]); // {key: "value2.2"}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20arr1%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20key%3A%20%22value1%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20key%3A%20%22value2%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20key%3A%20%22value3%22%20%7D%5D%3B%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20new%20Array(...arr1)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(arr1%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2%22%7D%0Aconsole.log(arr2%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2%22%7D%0A%0Aarr2%5B1%5D.key%20%3D%20%22value2.2%22%0A%0Aconsole.log(arr1%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2.2%22%7D%0Aconsole.log(arr2%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2.2%22%7D))

To fix that you need to assign different instances, for example using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
this.outerTabs[1].InnerTabs = Object.assign({}, this.outerTabs[this.referencedOuterTab].InnerTabs);
```

In my example:

```
let arr1 = [{ key: "value1" }, { key: "value2" }, { key: "value3" }];
let arr2 = new Array(Object.assign({}, arr1[0]), Object.assign({}, arr1[1]), Object.assign({}, arr1[2]));

console.log(arr1[1]); // {key: "value2"}
console.log(arr2[1]); // {key: "value2"}

arr2[1].key = "value2.2"

console.log(arr1[1]); // {key: "value2"}
console.log(arr2[1]); // {key: "value2.2"}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20arr1%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20key%3A%20%22value1%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20key%3A%20%22value2%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20key%3A%20%22value3%22%20%7D%5D%3B%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20new%20Array(Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20arr1%5B0%5D)%2C%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20arr1%5B1%5D)%2C%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20arr1%5B2%5D))%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(arr1%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2%22%7D%0Aconsole.log(arr2%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2%22%7D%0A%0Aarr2%5B1%5D.key%20%3D%20%22value2.2%22%0A%0Aconsole.log(arr1%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2%22%7D%0Aconsole.log(arr2%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value2.2%22%7D))

Comment: Thanks. In my full example Object.assign didn't work, but it got me on the right track.
I cloned the `this.outerTabs[this.referencedOuterTab].InnerTabs` and then the code behaved as it should have.